# Calculations wont display in output

Tags: c++, function

I'm a student in a basic programming class and I'm trying to complete this program for a class assignment. It's a simple program that calculates compounded interest by the inputs of the user. However, when writing the code, I noticed that the the result is 0 even though based on the input I would expect otherwise. Could anyone tell me why the program isn't showing results?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

// Declarations of Prototype
void futureValue(double* presentValue, float* interestRate, int* months, double* value);

// List of variables
double presentValue = 0;
float interestRate = 0;
double value = 0;
int months = 0;

// Start of Main function
int main(void)
{
    cout << "What is the current value of the account?";
    cin >> presentValue;
    cout << "How many months will Interest be added to the account?";
    cin >> months;
    cout << "And what will be the Interest Rate of the account?";
    cin >> interestRate;
    cout << "After " << months << " months, your account balence will be $" << value << ".";
    return 0;
}

void futureValue()
{
    if (presentValue <= 0)
    {
        cout << "I'm sorry, you must have a current balence of more than 0.00 dollars to calculate.";
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        value = presentValue * pow(interestRate + 1, months);
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, you're not calling `futureValue()` at all ;-)

Comment: You're declaring `void futureValue(double* presentValue, float* interestRate, int* months, double* value);` but defining `void futureValue()`, and then not even calling it as usr said

Comment: There is no passing by reference here.

Comment: It's never too soon to stop using global variables.

Comment: When referring to calling the function, you mean inserting the variables that will be used in the function?

Comment: @DJJuly Do you know how to call a function? Like how you call `pow` inside of `futureValue`

Comment: maybe taking a look at https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/73-passing-arguments-by-reference/ might help you...

since you're not calling the function futureValue there's no way it will change the value.... also, maybe interesting to know, variables that do not change their value are not necessary needed to be given as a reference... 

Also, the definition of the your function needs to meet the declaration (including arguments)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You are not calling the `futureValue` function which would compute the `value` for you. Due to the `value` not being computed, it remains 0. Fix:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

// Declarations of Prototype
void futureValue(double* presentValue, float* interestRate, int* months, double* value);

// List of variables
double presentValue = 0;
float interestRate = 0;
double value = 0;
int months = 0;

// Start of Main function
int main(void)
{
    cout << "What is the current value of the account?";
    cin >> presentValue;
    cout << "How many months will Interest be added to the account?";
    cin >> months;
    cout << "And what will be the Interest Rate of the account?";
    cin >> interestRate;
    futureValue(); //Here we compute the value
    cout << "After " << months << " months, your account balence will be $" << value << ".";
    return 0;
}

void futureValue()
{
    if (presentValue <= 0)
    {
        cout << "I'm sorry, you must have a current balence of more than 0.00 dollars to calculate.";
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        value = presentValue * pow(interestRate + 1, months);
        return;
    }
}
```